# Exe файл в качестве операционной системы

Tags: c#, exe, ос

Идея такая: есть исполняемый файл, написанный на C# (консольная программа). Он находится на флешке. Нужно загрузить этот файл как операционную систему. В BIOS я, конечно, установлю порт как загрузочный. Но какой файл должен существовать и указывать на exe.

Хотелось бы получить ссылки на статьи или алгоритм как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Никак. Ехе понимает только ось. Винда. (Ну или там вайн)

Comment: Для работы исполняемого файла на платформе .net нужна реализация .net framework - например microsoft .net framework или mono. Фреймворк зависит от функций операционной системы. Так что вам кроме самого exe файла нужен еще будет свой .net framework, умеющий работать без операционной системы (как операционная система по сути). Проще взять C или C++ или ассемблер (или другой компилируемый в нативный код язык, правда не факт что любой язык подойдет), и написать минимальную ОС на нем.

Comment: Информация к размышлению: `в начале жёсткого диска, в самом первом секторе, располагается таблица разделов, имеющихся на диске, и, что важнее - MBR, Master Boot Record, главная загрузочная запись. В первом секторе для неё выделено 446 байт, и именно их BIOS выполняет, как программу. Она может делать всё, что угодно, точнее, всё, что программист сумеет втиснуть в этот смешной размер`.

Comment: Самый реалистичный на мой взгляд вариант, написать консольную прогу `.Net 5` под линукс и скомпилировать как сингл-файл, записать загрузочный образ минимального дистрибутива линукс на флешку и настроить его запускать вашу программу в качестве консоли. Как-то так. Это самый реалистичный вариант. Потому как писать на ассемблере или `C` собственную MBR и проч. подобие ОС вы не осилите никак, ну может после пару лет упорного изучения `C` и устройства ОС.

Comment: @Bulson MBR устарел, сейчас везде UEFI, на современных машинах MBR в принципе отсутствует на диске. Загрузчик надо пилить именно под EFI.

Comment: @aepot, ну хорошо, загрузчик можно даже не писать самому, а взять готовый `GRUB`. Но, остальное (ядро работы с CPU и памятью, драйвера для видео и клавиатуры и проч) на `C#` вы понимаете, что реализовать невозможно.

Comment: @aeport И кстати, MBR все равно используется, даже для дисков с разметкой [GPT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:GNU_GRUB_on_GPT_partitioned_hard_disk_drives.svg)

Comment: @Bulson я думаю, возможно, но очень сложно и вряд-ли это в принципе эффективно и безопасно. Можно конечно препарировать винду, оставив только ядро и запустить под ним экзешник. Про MBR, при наличии UEFI, MBR - излишество, и тип разметки диска здесь вообще не при чем, разные, очень слабо связанные между собой штуки. Загрузчик, сидящий в MBR может уметь какую угодно разметку переваривать. Что запишешь в нулевой "сектор", то там и будет работать. EFI - это новый загрузчик, уехавший с диска в Firmware, что стильно, модно и современно, и еще говорят, что безопасно.